# Phonegap 3.0 CLI issue android target number in build app

Tags: android, build, cordova

I am running MAC Phonegap 3.0 CLI to make my android webapp.
Got Android target 18 installed.

```
$ phonegap local build android
```

And so I got error :

```
[error] Please install Android target 17 (the Android 4.2 SDK). Make sure you have the latest Android tools installed as well. Run `android` from your command-line to install/update any missing SDKs or tools.
```

**QUESTION**
Is there a param to tell Phonegap to use target 18 ?
Or is it too soon for Phonegap 3.0 ?

Here is my Android SDK Manager:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am including my AndroidManifest.xml file. Look at the pink circle I put. This you have to change.
[image]

Comment: But the android XML doesn't get created until you can successfully add Android to the project...

Comment: How can I add the AndroidManifest.xml if I cannot add Android to my project?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a project.properties to tells "phonegap" which version of android you would like to use as follow:

target=android-

You can find out more here:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_command-line_index.md.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to look in file AndroidManifest.xml. You have android:minSdkVersion and android:targetSdkVersion. Specify the min. Version your app will run and targeted one. In your case 18. Hope you understand it if not contact me.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the wrong place

TRY THIS:   **phonegap local build android**

this will add the android to your platforms folder

Answer (score 0):

I think PhoneGap, when using `build`, uses by default the latest API version (target) installed. If you already used the command with a previous API and you want to use the newly installed, run:

```
phonegap platform update android
```