# Configuring Phonegap 3.0 with Android

Tags: android, cordova

I am configuring Phonegap 3.0 with Android Eclipse,When I am running android from Node.js Command prompt, It is giving error --Please install Android Target 17.Currently I am using ADT bundle SDK 4.3(API 18). In the SDK Manager only API 18 Version is showing. Please tell me how to update or download API 17 for Phonegap 3.0.

Comment: Please follow this link for the solution.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789524/phonegap-3-0-wants-android-17-but-i-want-android-18?rq=1

Comment: Please follow this link for the solution.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789524/phonegap-3-0-wants-android-17-but-i-want-android-18?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Use Android SDK Manager to download/install API 17. Click on the checkbox next to "Android 4.2.2 (API 17)" then click "Install packages..." then follow the prompts.